# Store Procedure to save the Query run date and the total in the HANA Database - Run everyday morning at 6:30

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, hana

Looking for some help with the stored procedure to save the query results every morning in "HANADB_Table" in HANA Database. The stored procedure should run the query every day, and append a new row every morning with the run date and the counts.
I have a query which currently gives me the result:

```
Run Date    Count 1 Count 2     Count 3
1-Jun   1125    63  1188
```

The table in the HANA database is something like this:

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE HANADB_Table (
    Run_Date DATE not null,
    Count1 INTEGER not null,
    Count2 INTEGER not null,
    Count3 INTEGER not null
);
```

The query that gives me the result is :

```
select current_date, sum(Count1), sum(Count2), sum(Count3)
from TableName;
```

All the help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the easy answer is to put a statement like the following into a stored procedure. That stored procedure then can be scheduled either via the **SAP HANA XS scheduler** ([YouTube video on HANA job scheduling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3THGIr5bwx0)) or an external tool, e.g. `cron`.

The statement would look like this

```
INSERT into "HANADB_Table" ( Run_Date, Count1, Count2, Count3)
                  (select current_date, sum(Count1), sum(Count2), sum(Count3)
                   from "TableName");
```

If you want to follow this approach you might consider using `BigInt` for the SUM columns instead, as aggregate values typically tend to get really large over time.

Also, this approach of timed snapshot aggregates usually is considered to be rather inflexible. In many scenarios, one would rather strive to be able to get the resulting aggregates for arbitrary points in time from the source table directly.